# Webpack not loading font files

Tags: webpack, urlloader

Im relatively new to all of this and have been struggling getting my fonts to be included into my style.css.

At first it was not loading the files due to the path being incorrect (apparently it was looking for relative path from root rather than within the fonts directory itself)

Not it seems to find the files but tells me I am using the wrong loader. 
See Below:

```
module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /\.jsx?$/,
        exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        query: {
          presets: ['react', 'es2015', 'stage-0'],
          plugins: ['react-html-attrs', 'transform-class-properties', 'transform-decorators-legacy'],
        }
      },
      {
        test: /\.scss?$/,
        loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract('css!sass')
      },
      {
        test: /\.(png|woff|woff2|eot|ttf|svg)$/,
        loader: 'url-loader?limit=100000'
      }
    ]
  },
```

The error I get is the following:
[image]

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: BTW I am not sure why it says "Cannot find module... main.scss" if I remove the @import for the fonts it finds it just fine...

Answer (score 0):

You sure it is `url-loader` but not `file-loader` ?

Because `url-loader` uses dataUrls and `file-loader` emits files.

Let's try the following and see it that works ~

`{ test: /\.woff(2)?(\?v=[0-9]\.[0-9]\.[0-9])?$/, loader: "url-loader?limit=10000&minetype=application/font-woff" },
      { test: /\.(ttf|eot|svg)(\?v=[0-9]\.[0-9]\.[0-9])?$/, loader: "file-loader" }`

Comment: No luck, strangely enough though this did solve another problem I was having within my fonts directory where the relative paths were not exactly correct. But otherwise same error: "Module parse failed: ... Line 1: Unexpected token ILLEGAL ... You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type."